# IIS 8.5 not logging all requests

Tags: logging, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I'm having an issue where IIS 8.5 on Server 2012 R2 is not logging requests properly. It was working fine up until about a week ago - producing log files >10mb. This information was useful for our analytics processing. Currently, the log files contain very little information, with the occasional request that is logged - producing log files <100kb. I'm unsure what changed to cause it to stop.

I copy these files periodically and analyze them at a separate location. The log files for last month were all between 1mb and 14mb each. The same log files were later shown as <100kb files. The `Date Modified` for each does not appear to have changed. I have copies of both sets of files.

Reading through other similar-sounding issues with IIS6 and IIS7 led me to check comparable settings:

- Permissions on logging directories match between my test server and production server. This does not appear to have changed.
- Settings have not changed - `dontLog = False`, `selectiveLogging = logAll`
- `Use local time for file naming and rollover` is unchecked.
- W3C logging settings are default
- Changing `Log Event Destination` to `Both log file and ETW event` produces same results. Limited requests logged.
- Restarting services & IIS yielded no changes
- Restarting server resulted in no changes.
- W3C Logging Service set to `Automatic` startup

  ---

  ```
  #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
  #Version: 1.0
  #Date: 2015-10-08 15:22:58
  #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
  2015-10-08 15:22:58 x.x.x.x GET / - 80 - x.x.x.x MSIE+6.0 - 200 0 0 187
  2015-10-08 15:27:58 x.x.x.x GET / - 80 - x.x.x.x MSIE+6.0 - 200 0 0 78
  2015-10-08 15:32:58 x.x.x.x GET / - 80 - x.x.x.x MSIE+6.0 - 200 0 0 93
  ```

Comment: which solution about your problem ? ***IIS logs*** ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved, however my understanding of active directory and domain controllers is lacking.

Here are the conditions that restored the log files:

- Log files were being kept, just not visible to my account. (not stored on the server/file system?)
- There was a trust relationship failure between the server and domain.
- Once the trust relationship between domain and server, including accounts, was restored, the log files were once again available. This includes all of the log files generated for the duration of the issue.

Hopefully this information is useful to someone in the future.